# Count number of 'coin'p coins in a "machine"

Tags: java

For my recent assignment I've been tasked to create a ticket machine which accepts payments and allows you to cancel them. A recent extension to the assignment was to count how many of the pennies being added were a certain type of penny, e.g 10p, 20p, 50p.

I managed to get the program to accurately count the number of 10p within the machine but I'm having a trouble when I tried with 20's.

For example when I run the program at the moment it runs perfectly for the 10ps however when I run it for 20ps I get these results back:

Test: Count coins

ERROR: Expected 4 - 20p coins found 5 - 20p coins

Heres the code that calculates how many 10/20/50ps are in the machine:

```
class ProcessMoney
{
int ticket;
int cost = 0;
int machine;
int pence = 0;
int calc = 0;

public void setTicketPrice( int amount ) {

   ticket = amount;

}

public int getTicketPrice() { 

   return ticket;

    }


public void add( int coin ) {

    cost = cost + coin;

    if ( coin == 10 ){
        calc = calc + 1;
    }


    } 

public boolean enough() { return true; }

public int getPaidSoFar() { return cost; }

  public void cancel() {

      cost = 0;

} 

public void bought() {

      machine = machine + cost;
      cost = 0;

    }

  public int moneyInMachine() { 

      return machine;

}

public int getCoins( int coin ) {

     if ( coin == 10 ){
     pence = machine * 100;
     calc = pence / 1000;
     }
     else if ( coin == 20 ){
         pence = machine * 100;
         calc = pence / 2000;
        }

     return calc;
    }
}
```

Heres the code for testing it:

```
class Main
{ 
  private static ProcessMoney pm = new ProcessMoney();

  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    int res = 0, expected = 100;

    test( "setTicketPrice() & getTicketPrice() ");

    pm.setTicketPrice( expected );
    res = pm.getTicketPrice();
    check( res == expected, 
          "Ticket price is %d should be %d", res, expected );

    expected = 200;
    pm.setTicketPrice( expected );
    res = pm.getTicketPrice();
    check( res == expected, 
          "Ticket price is %d should be %d", res, expected );

    test( "add() & getPaidSoFar()");

    pm.add( 10 ); pm.add( 20 ); pm.add( 30 );
    expected = 60;
    res = pm.getPaidSoFar();
    check( res == expected, 
          "Money entered into machine is %d should be %d", res, expected );
    pm.add( 20 ); pm.add( 40 ); pm.add( 40 );
    expected = 160;
    res = pm.getPaidSoFar();
    check( res == expected, 
          "Money entered into machine is %d should be %d", res, expected );

    test( "add() & cancel()");

    pm.add( 10 ); pm.add( 20 ); pm.add( 30 );
    expected = 0;
    pm.cancel();
    res = pm.getPaidSoFar();
    check( res == expected, 
          "money entered into machine is now %d should be 0", res );

    pm.add( 100 ); pm.add( 200 ); pm.add( 300 );
    expected = 0;
    pm.cancel();
    res = pm.getPaidSoFar();
    check( res == expected, 
          "money entered into machine is now %d should be 0", res );

    test( "enough()");

    pm.setTicketPrice( 200 );
    pm.add( 100 ); pm.add( 100 ); pm.add( 0 );
    expected = 200;
    check( pm.enough(), 
          "Enough money entered into machine 200 for 200 ticket" );
    pm.cancel();

    pm.setTicketPrice( 210 );
    pm.add( 100 ); pm.add( 100 ); pm.add( 20 );
    expected = 200;
    check( pm.enough(), 
          "Enough money entered into machine 220 for 210 ticket" );
    pm.cancel();

    test( "bought() & moneyInMachine()");

    pm.setTicketPrice( 200 );
    pm.add( 100 ); pm.add( 100 ); pm.add( 0 );
    if ( pm.enough() )
    {
      pm.bought();
    }

    expected = 200;
    res = pm.moneyInMachine();
    check( expected == res,
          "Total money in machine %d should be %d", res, expected );
    res = pm.getPaidSoFar();
    check( res == 0, 
          "Money for ticket in machine is %d should be 0", res );
    pm.cancel();


    pm.setTicketPrice( 200 );
    pm.add( 100 ); pm.add( 100 ); pm.add( 10 );
    if ( pm.enough() )
    {
      pm.bought();
    }

    expected = 410;
    res = pm.moneyInMachine();
    check( expected == res,
          "Total money in machine %d should be %d", res, expected );
    res = pm.getPaidSoFar();
    check( res == 0, 
          "Money for ticket in machine is %d should be 0", res );

    test("Count coins");
    pm = new ProcessMoney();
    checkRecord( 10, 2 );
    checkRecord( 20, 4 );
    checkRecord( 50, 3 );
    checkRecord( 100, 3 );
    checkRecord( 200, 2 );

    System.out.println( "Success" );
  }

  private static void checkRecord( int coin, int howMany )
  {
     pm.setTicketPrice( howMany * coin );

     for ( int i=1; i<=howMany*2; i++ )
     {
       pm.add( coin );
     }
     pm.cancel();

     for ( int i=1; i<=howMany; i++ )
     {
       pm.add( coin );
     }

     pm.bought();
     int actual = pm.getCoins( coin );
     check( howMany == actual,
            "Expected %d - %dp coins found %d - %dp coins", 
             howMany, coin, actual, coin  );
  }

  private static String what = "";

  public static void check( boolean ok, String fmt, Object... params )
  {
    if ( ! ok )
    {
      System.out.println( what );
      System.out.print("ERROR: " );
      System.out.printf( fmt, params );
      System.out.println();
      System.exit(-1);
    }
  }

  public static void test( String str )
  {
    what = "Test: "  + str;
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger? You could easily find your problem that way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your machine money is not cleared out from one check call to the next.  Here is how I tested your code:

```
private static void checkRecord( int coin, int howMany )  {

 pm.setTicketPrice( howMany * coin );

 System.out.println("Before, Machine has"+pm.moneyInMachine());<---added print
 for ( int i=1; i<=howMany*2; i++ )
 {
   pm.add( coin );
 }
 pm.cancel();

 for ( int i=1; i<=howMany; i++ )
 {
   pm.add( coin );
 }

 pm.bought();
 System.out.println("After, Machine has"+pm.moneyInMachine());<---added print
 int actual = pm.getCoins( coin );
 check( howMany == actual,
        "Expected %d - %dp coins found %d - %dp coins", 
         howMany, coin, actual, coin  );}
```

Here is what it printed for me (I also stopped your system exit and always printed out):

```
Before, Machine has0
After, Machine has20
Test: Count coins
ERROR: Expected 2 - 10p coins found 2 - 10p coins
Before, Machine has20
After, Machine has100
Test: Count coins
ERROR: Expected 4 - 20p coins found 5 - 20p coins
Before, Machine has100
After, Machine has250
Test: Count coins
ERROR: Expected 3 - 50p coins found 5 - 50p coins
Before, Machine has250
After, Machine has550
Test: Count coins
ERROR: Expected 3 - 100p coins found 5 - 100p coins
Before, Machine has550
After, Machine has950
Test: Count coins
ERROR: Expected 2 - 200p coins found 5 - 200p coins
```

Comment: Just to clarify, since the print is a bit odd looking.  Your 20 from the first call (where 2 10p coins are added), are still in the machine.  So the check finds 100p total when it expected 80.  So you either need to clear the coins in the machine from one check to the next, or take that into account for the number expected.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `add(int coin)` method. That's where your problem <strike>is</strike> starts.

Also @Msonic's advice to use a debugger is excellent.